# stopped an video by range using flag?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html5-video, mediaelement.js

i stopped an video by video range and start an video from end of the video using flag, in that i am facing a problem is while i refresh an page code is working fine.

i didnt do refresh its not working ie., video is not pause.

below is my code:

```
MediaElement('player1', {
    success: function (me) {
        var flag = true;
        var me = document.getElementById('player1');
        me.play();
        me.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
            if (flag) {
                if (this.currentTime > 4.10234 && this.currentTime < 4.451111) {
                    this.pause();
                    flag = false
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = me.currentTime;
        }, false);
        document.getElementById('playmode')['onclick'] = function () {
            if (me.paused) me.play();
            else me.pause();
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[]` from `onclick` like,

```
document.getElementById('playmode').onclick = function () {
    if (me.paused) me.play();
    else me.pause();
};
```

Don't `reassign` `me` variable

```
 success: function (me) {// me is your player here
    var flag = true;
    //var me = document.getElementById('player1'); //remove this line
    me.play();
    me.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
        if (flag) {
            if (this.currentTime > 4.10234 && this.currentTime < 4.451111) {
                this.pause();
                flag = false
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = me.currentTime;
    }, false);
    document.getElementById('playmode').onclick = function () {
        if (me.paused) me.play();
        else me.pause();
    };
```

Comment: s i did what u said,no change . for first time its working when after refresh